# How to add two symbolic functions?

Tags: octave

I have 2 symbolic functions:

```
fun = @(x) sum((5-2*x+(7-5*x)*A-B).^2);
fun2 = @(x) sum((8-2*x+(6-5*x)*A-B).^2);
```

(`A` and `B` are matrices).

Now I want to add these 2 functions into a new function `func3`:

```
fun3 = fun + fun2
```

But I get this error :

```
error: binary operator '+' not implemented for 'function handle' by 'function handle' operations
```

How can I add the two functions?

Comment: What about `fun3 = @(x) fun(x) + fun2 (x) `

Comment: Those are not symbolic functions. They are anonymous functions with symbolic parameters. See `symfun` if you want to create symbolic functions. Or just use symbolic expressions.